# Storing Ratio as number in MySQL database column

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, database-schema

I want to store ratios in my database. An example of ratios are: `4:5, 6:7`, etc. I want to make a query based on the ratios.

I thought about storing them as decimals (9,3) in MySQL in order for to query them as numbers and not texts. A ratio can be a long number like `1.77777777778`  for 16:9.

What is the appropriate way to store it in MySQL database in order to query it later.

Comment: Two columns, `numerator` and `denominator`.

Comment: Seems like the best solution, write and I will accept. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store them in two columns, `numerator` and `denominator`.

Either the code that inserts and updates the data should ensure that the ratios are reduced to lowest form, or when you're comparing you'll need to perform division, e.g.

```
SELECT blah
FROM table
WHERE numerator/denominator = 16/9
```

Comment: Thank you Barmar and the other people who helped as well.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to store it as 2 columns.
Since 4:5 and 8:10 produces same results, you can get the exact values if stored in separate colums.

You can save as 2 INTEGER or NUMERIC values.

Your select query can be:

```
SELECT NUM1, NUM2, NUM1/NUM2 AS RATIO FROM MY_TABLE
```